# twitter-bootstrap Collapse stops working after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

At first I would like to say thank you to the TwitterBootsrap team for what they are producing  but the documentation need much more work.

I am having the code of the site example at my site:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                <div class="accordion-group">
                  <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1</a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                      Sentence 1
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-group">
                  <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">Collapsible Group Item #2</a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                      Sentence2
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-group">
                  <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">Collapsible Group Item #3</a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                      Sentence3
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

The problem is that each row of the accordion opens and closes only once and then the accordion becomes useless. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This sounds like a JavaScript error. Are you using any other libraries  than Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery? Also, which versions are you using? Does this happen in every browser (Chrome, FF, IE9, etc)? I've seen such things occur when `$.support.transition` is used by other libraries in incompatible ways.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. Updated jQuery to latest version (1.9.1) fixed it.